# Abstract generic class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract generic class in typescript which has a generic method with parameter of class type variable. I tried to implement abstract method in derived class and found that typescript compiler doesn’t check type of parameter in derived method.

Here is an example. I expect that it fails at compile time on **process** method on **Class1** because type of parameter is wrong.

Am I doing something wrong? Or it is by design? Or bug in typescript compiler

```
class Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class Customer {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

export abstract class BaseClass<TParam> {
  protected abstract process(param: TParam): void;
}

export class Class1 extends BaseClass<Customer> {
  protected process(param: Product): void {
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The behavior is not a bug.

TypeScript uses a [structural](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) type system, so that two object types are compatible if they have compatible properties, even if the types have different names or come from different named classes/interfaces.

Note, then, that `Customer` is assignable to `Product`, since every `Customer` has a `number`-valued `id` property and a `string`-valued `name` property.  The reverse isn't true; `Product` is not assignable to `Customer`, since not every `Product` has the requisite `address` property.

Is this a mistake?  Is it a problem for your code that the compiler thinks that a `Customer` is a special kind of `Product`?  If it is, the easiest way around this is to add a property to each type that the compiler can use to distinguish them.  For example:

```
class Product {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  type?: "product" 
}

class Customer {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  address!: string;
  type?: "customer"
}
```

Now the code will give you an error, as desired:

```
export abstract class BaseClass<TParam> {
  protected abstract process(param: TParam): void;
}

export class Class1 extends BaseClass<Customer> {
  protected process(param: Product): void { // error!
    //      ~~~~~~~ <-- Type 'Customer' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

---

Or maybe it's fine that the compiler thinks that a `Customer` is a special kind of `Product`.  In this case, you can leave your types alone and we can examine why `process()` does not lead to a compiler error:

```
export class Class1 extends BaseClass<Customer> {
  protected process(param: Product): void { // no error
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

In this case, `BaseClass<Customer>` should have a `process()` method that accepts a `Customer`.  But this `process()` accepts the wider type `Product` instead.  Is that okay?  Yes!  Because if `process()` accepts any `Product` argument, then it *definitely* accepts any `Customer` argument (because a `Customer` is a special kind of `Product`, and so `Class1` properly extends `BaseClass<Customer>`).  This is a demonstration of how method arguments are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Contravariant_method_argument_type); a subclass method is allowed to accept *wider* arguments than the same method on the supertype.  TypeScript does allow method arguments to be contravariant, and so there is no error.

It *isn't* safe for method arguments to be [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_argument_type) (where subclass methods accept *more specific argument types* than their respective superclass methods), but some languages *including TypeScript* allow this to represent some common use cases.  That is, TypeScript allows method arguments to be both contravariant and covariant, also called [bivariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant), despite its lack of type safety.  So if you had done it the other way, there would also be no error:

```
export class Class2 extends BaseClass<Product> {
  protected process(param: Customer): void { // no error, bivariant
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

---

To recap: you can add properties to `Customer` and `Product` to cause them to be unrelated structurally, or you can leave them alone and `Class1.process()` will compile without error.  Either way, the compiler is behaving as intended.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for so detailed explanation.
I expected behavior like in C#